# Calculating ln (natural logarithm) in games

Tags: mathematics, game-mechanics, optimization

I am developing a game for tablets using the Marmalade SDK and Cocos 2dX.

In my game I have implemented a separation steering behavior in order to keep some of my characters separated from eachother. Currently I am calculating the magnitude of this steering force using a y = -ln(x) function, in which ln is the natural logarithm.

However, I am wondering if this is a wise choice of function, because it may be costly for the processor to calculate this, just like the square root function.

What do you think, should I try to replace my function for something similar to optimize my game's performance, or there will be minimal gain in replacing a logarithm function for a 1 / x function, for example.

Comment: If your profiler doesn't tell you this is a bottleneck, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you'll notice the difference in performance. Echoing Josh - in general it's best to build the game/app in a straightforward way and use profiling to see where your actual performance issues are, if/once they show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. Definitely don't worry about this.**

Even if your game calls `log()` a lot of times in a frame, that's still very, very unlikely to be a CPU bottleneck. Memory access latency is where the bulk of you CPU time is going to be spent on. To give you an idea of the disparity between instruction costs and memory access costs, take a look at this segment from the talk [Data-Oriented Design and C++](https://youtu.be/rX0ItVEVjHc?t=28m54s) from CppCon 2014.

According to sample data collected by the author, a costly instruction like a square-root is around ~15-20 cycles latency. A more expensive instruction like sine/cosine is in ~100-150 cycles range. A memory access in main RAM, resulting from a cache miss, is going to have anything from 200 or more cycles of latency. So modern optimizations should focus a lot more in making sure data locality and CPU caches are well used, rather than optimizing at the instruction level, like in the old days when memory and CPU clocks weren't so far apart.

Comment: Well, AFAIK it's not so much the bandwidth of the main memory (i.e. the clock) but the simple fact that the data needs so much time to get to the CPU compared to today's clock speeds. That doesn't affect your conclusion with which I fully agree but I thought I'd add this. This also explains why prefetching is so effective.